# Django wrong precedence of templates?

Tags: python, django, templates

It took me forever to find out why a template was not getting overridden, only to find that it seems Django simply does not use the correct precedence in overriding the templates.

The templates I'm trying to change are the ones for changing the user's password, which are loaded for the URL `/accounts/password/change`.

I have my modified templates in `mysite/myapp/templates/registration`; the system default templates are at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration`. When templates are present in both these directories, Django uses the system (`/Library`) ones. Huh?

When  I remove the templates in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration`
, the correct ones (i.e. mine, in `mysite/myapp/templates/registration`) are loaded.

How to fix this issue? That is, how to make Django load my overridden templates without having the delete the original templates found in the `/Library`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create an admin directory inside the templates dir in which you set the templates you want to override

> In order to override one or more of them, first create an admin directory in your project’s templates directory. This can be any of the directories you specified in TEMPLATE_DIRS.

[Read the Django doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Comment: hmm, this worked, thanks. But how come django still finds it even though it wasn't in the template dirs if I delete the default templates?

Comment: It must use some sort of priority order list: use override OR check default OR  check local